# Changing the interval of x axis on R

Tags: r

I am struggling with my x axis. For now my axis has the same interval between the tick but I would like to have the same interval between 10,0000 - 20,000 - 40,000 - 80,0000 - 160,000.[I want the same axis as in the picture if possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEORe.png)

Here is my code :

```
x <- seq(3000, 160000)
y <- 0.00000339*x + 0.389830508
plot(x, y, xaxt='n', ylim=c(0.4,0.9),yaxp =c(.5,.9,4), xlab = "Annual income", ylab ="Fraction of population experiencing",col=0.8)

axis(1, c(10000,20000,40000,80000, 160000),srt=90)
```

Comment: Your axes are already what you want them to be. The reason you may not see them would be that your plot window is currently too small. E.g. zooming a little should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a `log=`arithmic scale on the x axis.

```
plot(x, y, xaxt='n', ylim=c(0.4, 0.9), xlim=c(9.8e3, 16e4),
     log='x', yaxp=c(.5,.9,4), xlab="Annual income", 
     ylab="Fraction of population experiencing",
     col=8)

axis(1, 2^(0:4)*1e4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, define the actual points on the x-axis where you want to place ticks:

```
x_seq <- (160000-3000)/5*1:5
[1]  31400  62800  94200 125600 157000
```

Now define `x_seq[1]` as the starting point of the `xlim` range:

```
plot(x, y, xaxt='n', 
     ylim=c(0.4,0.9),xlim = c(x_seq[1], 160000),
     yaxp =c(.5,.9,4), xlab = "Annual income", ylab ="Fraction of population experiencing",col=0.8)
```

Finally, use `x_seq` to define the locations `at` which you want the labels to appear:

```
axis(1, at = x_seq, labels = c(10000,20000,40000,80000,160000), srt=90)
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

Even more precisely, you would also use `x_seq[5]` as the endpoint of the x-axis range:

```
plot(x, y, xaxt='n', 
     ylim=c(0.4,0.9),xlim = c(x_seq[1], x_seq[5]),
     yaxp =c(.5,.9,4), xlab = "Annual income", ylab ="Fraction of population experiencing",col=0.8)
```